# Frozen Mock is not the one that is being injected - Moq

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I'm trying to mock the UserService class. The problem is that if I use `fixture.Register<UserManager<User>>(...)` then it registers only the `UserManager<User>`, and this registration does not apply on `Mock<UserManager<User>>`.

The biggest problem is that the mock with `[Frozen]` attribute is not the one that is being injected into sut's contructor. Example:

**UserManager customization**

```
public class UserManagerCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Register(() =>
        {
            var mgr = new Mock<UserManager<User>>(Mock.Of<IUserRoleStore<User>>(),
                null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

            mgr.Setup(x => x.DeleteAsync(It.IsAny<User>()))
                    .ReturnsAsync(IdentityResult.Success);

            mgr.Setup(x => x.CreateAsync(It.IsAny<User>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
                .ReturnsAsync(IdentityResult.Success);

            mgr.Setup(x => x.UpdateAsync(It.IsAny<User>()))
                .ReturnsAsync(IdentityResult.Success);

            mgr.Setup(x => x.AddToRoleAsync(It.IsAny<User>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
                .ReturnsAsync(IdentityResult.Success);

            return mgr.Object;
        });
    }
}
```

**AutoMoqData Attribute**

```
public class AutoMoqDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    public static IFixture FixtureFactory()
    {
        var f = new Fixture();

        f.Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization() { ConfigureMembers = true });
        f.Customize(new UserManagerCustomization());

        return f;
    }

    public AutoMoqDataAttribute() : base(FixtureFactory) { }
}
```

**System under test**

```
public class IdentityService : IIdentityService
{
    private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IInfrastructureDbContext _dbContext;

    public IdentityService(
        UserManager<User> userManager,
        IMapper mapper,
        IInfrastructureDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task<string> CreateUserAsync(UserViewModelIn user)
    {
        Guard.Against.Null(user, nameof(user));

        User newUser = _mapper.Map<User>(user);
        newUser.ProfileImage = new ProfileImage();

        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, user.Password);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(newUser, "User");
        }

        return result.Succeeded ? newUser.Id : null;
    }
}
```

**The test**

```
[Theory]
[AutoMoqData]
public async Task CreateUser_ValidUser_ShouldCreateValidUserRecord(
    [Frozen] Mock<UserManager<User>> userManagerMock,
    IdentityService sut, // IdentityService injects UserManager<User>
    UserViewModelIn userVm)
{
    // Act
    await sut.CreateUserAsync(userVm);

    // Assert
    userManagerMock.Verify(m => m
        .CreateAsync(
            It.IsAny<User>(),
            It.IsAny<string>()
        ),
        Times.Once);
}
```

`userManagerMock` is not the same mock that gets passed to IdentityService's constructor, so this test always fails because the mock that I'm verified is not the one that IdentityService is callin upon user creation.

I want the `fixture.Register<Service>` to also cover the `fixture.Register<Mock<Service>>`, I don't know why this is not the default behavior.

Comment: We will need to see more details to better confirm the described behavior. Show the subject under test and the full test scenario so that we can recreate the problem.

Comment: @Nkosi Done, I've added some more information